# Semantic release with google cloud CI/CD using git annotation tag

Tags: gradle, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-repository

I am releasing the artifact to the Artifact registry in the Google cloud. I want to have a semantic versioning release cycle using the git annotation tag to the master branch.

```
steps:
  # This step show the version of Gradle
  - id: Gradle Install
    name: gradle:7.4.2-jdk17-alpine
    entrypoint: gradle
    args: ["--version"]

  # This step build the gradle application
  - id: Build
    name: gradle:7.4.2-jdk17-alpine
    entrypoint: gradle
    args: ["assemble"]

  - id: Publish
    name: gradle:7.4.2-jdk17-alpine
    entrypoint: "sh"
    args:
      - -c
      - |
        if [ $BRANCH_NAME == 'master' ]
        then
          echo "Branch is = $BRANCH_NAME"
          gradle publish
        fi
```

In the last publish step, I want to write a condition for finding the latest git tag for versioning like 1.0.0, and should run that step on only when that condition matched. Similar to the other auto tools

**Now on TRAVIS CI/CD**

```
skip_cleanup: true
on:
    all_branches: false
    branch: master
    tag: true
    condition: "$TRAVIS_TAG = ~^v\d+\.\d+\.\d+$"
```

What is the equivalent of the above semantic versioning release in GCP. How to write the regular expression condition on google cloud build

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Build doesn't have semantic versioning as it doesn't include a sequential build number that increments depending on the number of commits. [Substituting variable values](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values) would be the nearest equivalent for semantic versioning as there is an option for [users have the option to define their own substitutions](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#using_user-defined_substitutions).

Here's a sample `yaml` file for user-defined substitution:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build',
         '--build-arg',
         'node_version=${_NODE_VERSION_1}',
         '-t',
         'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/build-substitutions-nodejs-${_NODE_VERSION_1}',
         '.']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build',
         '--build-arg',
         'node_version=${_NODE_VERSION_2}',
         '-t',
         'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/build-substitutions-nodejs-${_NODE_VERSION_2}',
         '.']
substitutions:
    _NODE_VERSION_1: v6.9.1 # default value
    _NODE_VERSION_2: v6.9.2 # default value
images: [
    'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/build-substitutions-nodejs-${_NODE_VERSION_1}',
    'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/build-substitutions-nodejs-${_NODE_VERSION_2}'
]
```

You can check the links below for additional information on `substitutions` for Cloud Build:

- [Get a (pseudo) sequential build number in Google Cloud Build](https://nieldw.medium.com/get-a-pseudo-sequential-build-number-in-google-cloud-build-85ae591cf86)
- [Cloud Build Recipes - Incrementing Build Numbers](https://ryanharter.com/blog/2019/01/cloud-build-recipes-incrementing-build-numbers/)

Let me know if you have questions or clarifications.